# How to create a grid which you can scroll both vertically and horizontally, which contains random sized elements, and works with recyclerview?

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview, grid, android-flexboxlayout

I am a beginner, and i tried to find an answer but everything i found was from 2013 and earlier. I want to create a grid which you can scroll in any direction, (as a zoomed in picture), which contains items of different sizes which are generated randomly, then i want to populate them with a recycler view. I will attach an illustration, maybe you would understand it better.[As you can see, the thick outline is the phone screen and whenever you scroll the view, it generates new items which are populated by a recycler view.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CQQfH.png)

I thought of using Google's FlexBox Layout for generating the items but i don't really know how to create that scrollable view. I would literally pay to get this done.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can make RecyclerView scroll in Both way. U can Create Nested RecyclerView if that is what you are looking for.